Fraudulent contract or valid?
What do you think about this code and BOT recommendation? I am attaching the video. In the description of the video, the code. I suspect it's a scam. In lines 109 and 113 of the code, there is a keccak256 hash with the return hash. What do you think, is it a scam or real? The code contains the address of wETH, it is true. Where can I check the contract and the BOT? Guy video just 2 days public watch 2K people after not being public on Youtube. My opinion this big scam to.
Video:https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yTVnW73RZQ4
Code: https://gptbotcode.pages.dev/

Without opening the links, 99% scam. If something is too good to be true, it is. Lots of this kind of scams through Youtube videos.
